# Django cannot assign variable to objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

when i'm trying to add data to uer in many to many
as showen in views code below

***views.py***

```
def playList(request, name, language):
    playlist = {
        'classic': Classic,
    }
    playlist2 = {
        'classic': 'classic',
    }
    num = {
        'ar': 1,
        'en': 2,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = FavoriteForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            x = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            x.playlist2[name].add(playlist[name].objects.get(id=request.POST.get(playlist2[name])))
    form = playlist[name].objects.filter(lang=num[language])
    context = {}
    for i in form:
        context[i] = i
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'playlist': playlist2[name],

    }
    return render(request, 'playlist.html', context)
```

get this error that str object has no attr objects

***'str' object has no attribute 'objects'***

when i'm change str to istance

as showen in views code below

***views.py***

```
def playList(request, name, language):
    playlist = {
        'classic': Classic,
    }
    playlist2 = {
        'classic': Profile.classic,
    }
    num = {
        'ar': 1,
        'en': 2,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = FavoriteForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            x = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            x.playlist2[name].add(playlist[name].objects.get(id=request.POST.get(playlist2[name])))
    form = playlist[name].objects.filter(lang=num[language])
    context = {}
    for i in form:
        context[i] = i
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'playlist': playlist2[name],

    }
    return render(request, 'playlist.html', context)
```

i get this error that
profile has no attr playlist2

***'Profile' object has no attribute 'playlist2'***

and this is my model code

***modles.py***

```
class Classic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    music = models.FileField(upload_to='', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    lang = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    classic = models.ManyToManyField(Classic, blank=True)
    workOut = models.ManyToManyField(WorkOut, blank=True)
    chillOut = models.ManyToManyField(ChillOut, blank=True)
    romantic = models.ManyToManyField(Romantic, blank=True)
    happy = models.ManyToManyField(Happy, blank=True)
    sad = models.ManyToManyField(Sad, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `x.playlist2[name].add`, since that will look for the `playlist2` attribute of `x`.

You can make use of [**`getattr(..)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). If you perform `getattr(x, 'y')`, then this is equivalent to `x.y`:

```
def playList(request, name, language):
    playlist = {
        'classic': Classic,
    }
    playlist2 = {
        'classic': 'classic',
    }
    num = {
        'ar': 1,
        'en': 2,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = FavoriteForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            x = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            getattr(x, playlist2[name]).add(playlist[name].objects.get(id=request.POST.get(playlist2[name])))
    form = playlist[name].objects.filter(lang=num[language])
    context = {}
    for i in form:
        context[i] = i
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'playlist': playlist2[name],

    }
    return render(request, 'playlist.html', context)
```